# Msgs not getting printed

Tags: python

I am new to python. Below is the program to validate the phone number and country.
in main(), the print msgs are not getting printed.
am I doing something wrong? can someone take a look and advice?

```
import phonenumbers

import phonenumbers.phonenumberutil

def validNumber(phone_number,country):

    try: 
        parsed = phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse(phone_number,country),
                                            phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
    except:
        parsed = str(None)
        print(parsed)
    return parsed
        
def main():

    while True:
        phone_number=input('Enter your telephone number: ')
        country=input('Enter your country: ')

        phone_number = phone_number.replace('+', '', 1)
    
        parsed = validNumber(phone_number,country)
        
        
        error_msg = "The phone format for passed country is wrong"
                 
        try:
            pn = phonenumbers.parse(parsed,country)
            
            if phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn) and phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn):
                print ("Possible %s, Valid %s, Explain: %s" % (phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn), phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn), pn))
        except phonenumbers.NumberParseException as e:
            print(e, error_msg)
main()
```

Comment: `If` statements get evaluated (entered into) only when their condition evaluates to true. To simulate this try changing `phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn) and phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn):` to `True` and that should print out some messages but it won't be what you want. After you do that, try to figure out why your initial condition isn't giving you the result you want

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Print the values `phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn)` and `phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn)` above of the `if` statement. One of the values is probably false, which means you never enter the `if` block.

Comment: I corrected the code and it works